# How to use the integral sum to determine if a series converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've been stuck with a question for some time now.

The problem is this:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{1}{\ln(n^2)}$$

I get stuck when I try to integrate
$$\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n^2)}$$

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Notice that according to handy-dandy log rules, we have

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\ln(n^2)}=\frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\ln(n)}$$

Then notice that for all $n>0$, $\sqrt n>\ln(n)\implies\frac1{\ln(n)}>\frac1{\sqrt n}$ and apply the comparison test.

---

Alternatively, if you insisted on using the integral test, [see here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function)